# Should event times specified in UTC while generating ICS files, to avoid issues with myriad calendaring applications

Tags: timezone, icalendar

Handling timezones is tricky enough to say the least. And when it gets into generating ics files for scheduling meetings/events, it gets messier.

There have ben plenty of queries out on the internet, asking why the "meeting time is off by one hour after importing an ics file into outlook/google calendar, microsoft exchange server" etc.

Though i have researched quite a bit on this, including following the answers/suggestions on those trails, haven't quite figured out "the right method" of handling event time and what is the best practice around specifying timezone information in ics files.

Should it be that, the event times(start/end, recurring event times) be converted to UTC, and leave the conversion of time to correct timezone, to the consumer of ics file:Outlook, Google calendar?

Answer (score 5):

No.  Most events cannot be scheduled by UTC.  If it were that simple, that's how we would do it.  It's a lot more intricate.

Imagine you had a meeting every day at 10:00 AM, US Pacific Time, starting January 1st.   That would be 6:00 PM UTC - so you put that in your invitation and expect all to work itself out.  It all works fine, until the second Sunday in March, when daylight saving time goes into effect.  Your 6:00 PM UTC meeting would then line up with 11:00 AM Pacific Time - which is not how you intended the meeting to be scheduled.

But wait - it gets worse.  The DST rules can actually *change*.  This last happened in the USA in 2007, but it happens all the time in different parts of the world.  Sometimes it's not just the DST that changes, but the base offset itself.  If you schedule by UTC, you're setting up the expectation that everything you know about time zones will be exactly as it currently is - but nobody can predict the future.

Proper scheduling requires all of the following:

- The original local time value of the event
- A time zone identifier - preferably one from the [IANA time zone database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)
- All systems to be kept updated with [time zone data updates](https://mm.icann.org/mailman/listinfo/tz-announce)
- Governments to play nice and allow sufficient time for updates to be propagated

The last one is really important, and there's little you can do about it.  In recent years, countries such as [Egypt, Morocco](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/egypt-morocco-dst-ramadan-2014.html), and [Fiji](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/fiji-starts-dst-2014.html) have made changes with just a few days or a few weeks notice.  Even large countries like [Russia change their time zones](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-abandons-permanent-summer-time.html) - so you have to be prepared for updates.  You can review the long history of time zone updates, and watch for future changes [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/).

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson for the insights. Here are my observations:  1. Yes,i agree that all ics consuming clients need to be updated with latest tz data for scheduling to work fine. But, that expectation is needed regardless of whether the time is specified with tzid or in UTC. If the clients are using outdated data, then we'll have issues anyways.  2. for recurring events, when we speicfy the RRULE, the converted time for each RRULE would have taken care of the DST transition time, right?  This is how google seems to be handling it [link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/2367918?hl=en)

Comment: Metoo: Thanks @MattJohnson for the insights. I still think this "solution" is not a solution at all. What happens if you have a recurring meeting and the participants reside in different countries? The whole notion of the meeting always happening at the same local time goes out of the window, because different countries have different notions about daylight saving times; and different countries switch the times zones independently (as you mentioned).

It really doesn't make any sense to specify a point of time in "local time".

Comment: Oh another thing I just thought about: If you use local time to specify when a meeting is happening it's entirely possible to pick a local time which doesn't exist...
The switch from winter (normal) time to daylight saving time means that one particular hour gets skipped. If you specify your meeting time as local time and use the skipped hour, you just chose a point in time which doesn't exist.
Local time is just the plain wrong approach.

Comment: @IngoBlackman - As said in the answer, you need both the local time _of the event_ and a time zone identifier - to identify which local time zone that event belongs to.  A meeting with users in multiple time zones still needs to pick one that is dominant.  For example, it's common for a meeting to be in "10 AM Pacific Time".  If someone joins the meeting from another time zone, they'll have to determine their equivalent local time using both the rules of the meeting's time zone and the rules of their own time zone - as they are defined at the time of the meeting.

Comment: As far as picking a local time that doesn't exist:  For a single occurrence meeting, that is a validation concern that the system creating the event should prevent.  But for recurring meetings, the system needs to have an way to handle adjustment of the meeting for invalid and ambiguous occurrences due to DST transitions.  The most common approach is that ambiguous occurrences chose the first occurrence (ie. the daylight time, not the standard time) and invalid occurrences advance to a valid time by skipping ahead in the amount of the transition gap (usually 1 hour).

Comment: @MattJohnson: For recurring meetings I would just choose a different approach: Specify the start time as UTC. Add a modifier which says to which timezone to sync to. For each recurrence of the meeting, you then have to compare the time zone offset of this recurring meeting, to the time zone offset of the first meeting. If the offset has changed, you modify your meeting time accordingly.

Comment: @MattJohnson: "...10 AM Pacific Time", it's funny that you use this as an example :-). Someone tells you the meeting is "10 AM Pacific Time"... in winter; and then it turns out this someone resides in Arizona and actually means "Pacific Daylight Time"; because this someone thinks "Pacific Time" is the same as as "Mountain Standard Time'; which it is... in summer. Using local time to specify a point in time is just a big waste of time :-).

Comment: That's why computer's don't rely on what someone thinks.  We assign identifiers to time zones.  Pacific time's IANA identifier is `America/Los_Angeles`.  It comprises both PST and PDT, and understands the transitions between them.  So no, you don't store `"Pacific Time"`, you store `"America/Los_Angeles"`.  Sorry if that was unclear.