# Isn't iCalendar DTSTART with UTC bad?

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

The RFC5545 spec allows DTSTART to be specified in UTC time.  I'm thinking that's bad though, and could lead to be off by an hour.  For example, where I live we honor DST, but parts of Arizona do not.  So if the person in Arizona creates an event and it's just stored in UTC, won't I have a "one off" problem when DST switches on or off?

I'm thinking that I should *always* write the DTSTART and DTEND times with a TZID identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the app or program displaying the time should convert the time correctly for the given day.   It shouldn't matter what timezone you store the DTSTART in.   What matters is correct Timezone transition for the given date by the program that's displaying the time.

So around the daylight saving switchover of a destination.  two UTC times will map to the same destination time.

Aside: 
There are some very big well known systems don't do Timezone setup  for daylight saving zones in the best possible way, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Can you expand on your aside please?  I'm basically just converting to UTC on the client and then sending to the server, and then when it comes back from the server, I convert to local time.

Comment: Also, if there are no issues, I'm curious why something like Apple's iCal program would export them with timezones....so much easier if they just used UTC time for everything.

Comment: Sorry if my aside confused.  I don't like Microsoft' handling- it's a bit fiddly at the daylight saving cut over - but that's me being nitpicking.

Comment: Re apple I've no idea, but I have no problem with it - some people might argue they prefer to see their ics file in their own timezone,(I do ;) )

Answer (score 0):

DTSTART in UTC is bad mostly in the case of recurring events (especially with attendees). See [Should event times specified in UTC while generating ICS files, to avoid issues with myriad calendaring applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669096/should-event-times-specified-in-utc-while-generating-ics-files-to-avoid-issues) for example.